# Why Windows is saying 'Your device is running low on memory' when i have a lot of RAM available?

Tags: windows, windows-11

I'm using Windows 11. Wondering if this is a bug from the OS.

Today when I tried to open task manager by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>, I got this weird screen instead :

[image]

But the weird thing is, I have a lot of memory available:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you disabled the swap file? Even if you don't think it is needed it is absolutely necessary for how Windows works.

Comment: @Mokubai I don't even know how to do this... how can i check if this is disabled ?

Comment: Can you post what you see at step 4 of this guide: https://windowsreport.com/how-to-reset-virtual-memory-windows-11/ ? If the "Automatically manage paging file size" is unchecked then check it and click OK. It will reboot your system.

Comment: @Mokubai Sure, i just edited the question.

Comment: Odd. Everything looks okay. Could be a bug, Microsoft has made a lot of user interface blunders in their new "features" lately and I've never seen task manager give that kind of warning so it could be new.

Comment: @Mokubai I restarted and the issue went away... Very weird.

Comment: If it happens again, open the Memory tab on Task Manager. Look at the figures for committed memory. These messges are referring to virtual memory not RAM.